# Can't run .java files as Java apps in Jetbrains Intelji IDEA IDE

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

In Eclipse I can just "run" a file like so: [image] and it will give me the output of the .java file in the console.

I'm not seeing such an option in Jetbrains Intellji IDEA IDE. This is what I have available to me: [image]
What am I missing here?

Comment: So did you figure out how to run java class ? If not I will to try to help

Comment: Not yet no, haven't had the chance to try the answers below because of time constraints. This weekend I will.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you showing 'New project' dialog? It's not where run configurations are defined.
Here it is:
Run>Edit configurations:
[image]

Comment: Wtf...how?? I don't have half these options... here's how it looks: https://imgur.com/a/N5tMQ

Comment: You just need to click plus in the upper left corner to create a run configuration.

Comment: *sigh* Yea...it's been ages since I used Jetbrains IDE. Any tutorial how to set it up? I'm quite lost actually.

Comment: Here is official doc - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html#createExplicitly

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add Jdk.
Here is the full tutorial.

[Intellij idea_Before you start](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/tutorial-creating-running-and-packaging-your-first-java-application.html#before_you_start)

Comment: I have my SDK defined just fine. There's just no Option to run it... https://imgur.com/a/N5tMQ